# Firebase auth with custom user fields: React custom hook to manage user state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement authentication in my app using Firebase and I need to store some custom user fields (e.g. schoolName, programType, etc.) on the user documents that I'm storing in Firestore. I want to have these custom fields in my React state (I'm using Recoil for state management), and I'm very unsure of the best way to do this.

I currently have a Cloud Function responsible for creating a new user document when new auth users are created, which is great, however, I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to get that new user (with the custom fields) into my state, so I came up with a solution but I'm not sure if it's ideal and would love some feedback:

I define the `firebase/auth` functions (e.g. `signInWithPopup`, `logout`, etc.) in an external static file and simply import them in my login/signup forms.

To manage the user state, I created a custom hook `useAuth`:

```
const useAuth = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth); // firebase auth state
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useRecoilState(userState); // global recoil state

  useEffect(() => {
    // User has logged out; firebase auth state has been cleared; so clear app state
    if (!user?.uid && currentUser) {
      return setCurrentUser(null);
    }

    const userDoc = doc(firestore, "users", user?.uid as string);
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(userDoc, (doc) => {
      console.log("CURRENT DATA", doc.data());
      if (!doc.data()) return;
      setCurrentUser(doc.data() as any);
    });

    if (currentUser) {
      console.log("WE ARE UNSUBBING FROM LISTENER");

      unsubscribe();
    }

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [user, currentUser]);
};
```

This hook uses `react-firebase-hooks` and attempts to handle all cases of the authentication process:

1. New users
2. Existing users
3. Persisting user login on refresh (the part that makes this most complicated - I think)

To summarize the above hook, it essentially listens to changes in firebase auth state via `useAuthState`, then I add a `useEffect` which creates a listener of the user document in firestore, and when that user has successfully been inputted into the db by the Cloud Function, the listener will fire, and it will populate recoil state with `doc.data()` (which contains the custom fields) via `setCurrentUser`. As for existing users, the document will already exist, so a single snapshot will do the trick. The rationale behind the listener is the case of new users, where a second snapshot will be required as the first `doc.data()` will be undefined even though `useAuthState` will have a user in it, so it's essentially just waiting for the Cloud Function to finish.

I call this hook immediately as the app renders to check for a Firebase Auth user in order to persist login on refresh/revisit.

I've been messing around on this for quite some time, and this outlined solution does work, but I have come up with multiple solutions so I would love some guidance.

Thank you very much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Define `CurrentUser`, and `UserProfile` states

```
import { atom, selector } from "recoil";
import { type User } from "firebase/auth";

export const CurrentUser = atom<User | null | undefined>({
  key: "CurrentUser",
  dangerouslyAllowMutability: true,
  defaultValue: undefined,
});

export const UserProfile = atomFamily<Profile | null, string | undefined>({
  key: "CurrentUser",
  dangerouslyAllowMutability: true,
  get(uid) {
    return undefined;
  }
});
```

### Step 2: Listen to the authenticated user state changes

```
export const CurrentUser = atom<User | null | undefined>({
  key: "CurrentUser",
  dangerouslyAllowMutability: true,
  defaultValue: undefined,
  effects: [
    (ctx) => {
      if (ctx.trigger === "get") {
        // Import Firebase App instanced defined in a separate chunk
        const promise = import("../core/firebase")
          .then((fb) =>
            fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
              ctx.setSelf(user);
            })
          )
          .catch((err) => ctx.setSelf(Promise.reject(err)));
        return () => promise.then((unsubscribe) => unsubscribe?.());
      }
    },
  ],
});
```

### Step 3: Load user profile by Firebase user UID

```
export const UserProfile = atomFamily<User | null | undefined, string | undefined>({
  key: "CurrentUser",
  dangerouslyAllowMutability: true,
  get(uid) {
    return async function() {
      if (!uid) return null;
      import("../core/firebase").then(({ fs }) => {
        // TODO: Retrieve Firestore document with the user profile
        return getDoc(doc(dollection(fs, "users"), uid));
      });
    };
  }
});
```

### Step 4: Add React hooks

```
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil"; 

export function useCurrentUser() {
  return useRecoilValue(CurrentUser);
}

export function useCurrentUserProfile() {
  const me = useRecoilValue(CurrentUser);
  return useRecoilValue(UserProfile(me?.uid));
}
```

### Usage Example

```
import { useCurrentUser, useCurrentUserProfile } from "../state/firebase";

export function Example(): JSX.Element {
   const me = useCurrentUser(); // Firebase user object
   const profile = useCurrentUserProfile(); // Custom profile from Firestore
}
```

See https://github.com/kriasoft/cloudflare-starter-kit for a working example